# Query with more than one condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the salary from my `employees` table where the salary has to be between 6100 and 6400, and `first_name` is like a%.

I wrote this query :

```
select salary from employees where salary in (6100,6400) and first_name like 'a%';
```

But it shows no rows selected. How should I change the query to find rows that match both conditions?

Comment: When using the term 'between' you need to be careful to understand whether you want it to be inclusive, as Oracle's `between` is; do you want to include rows where the salary is *exactly* 6100 or 6400, or those greater than or equal to 6100 and less than 6400, say? (Since you get now rows from your query you don't have any that are exactly those values and also name first name starting with lower-case 'a', but it's a general consideration, and you may have some where fist name starts with upper-case 'A').

Answer (score 3):

Use `BETWEEN` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT salary 
FROM employees 
WHERE salary BETWEEN 6100 AND 6400
  AND first_name LIKE 'a%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BETWEEN this way

```
select salary 
from employees 
where salary BETWEEN 6100 AND 6400 
and first_name like 'a%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the `IN` statement rather than the `BETWEEN` statement, the data returned by your current query would only contain employee's with salaries equal to **6100** or **6400** and a first name starting with the lower case letter 'a'.

Please try the following:

```
SELECT SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE SALARY BETWEEN 6100 AND 6400
AND FIRST_NAME LIKE 'a%';
```